# Catch and call telephone number in WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I have a WKWebView that I want to ask to call a number when the number is selected. The contents of the web view contain the HTML anchor tag "tel:" and i am looking for a way to catch it. Which function is used to catch these tags?

Comment: Just verified the UITextView's dataDetectorTypes property work as you want, I'm not sure the WKWebView will forward the scheme navigation to iOS.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Set the webView's `navigationDelegate` property and implement the following function of the delegate (**WKNavigationDelegate**)

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    if navigationAction.request.url?.scheme == "tel" {
        UIApplication.shared.open(navigationAction.request.url!)
        decisionHandler(.cancel)
    } else {
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
}
```

Since iOS 10, you can also set `dataDetectorTypes` to `.phoneNumber` on your `WKWebViewConfiguration`. All detected phone numbers will transformed to contain links around the phone number and thus the above function will be fired with a URL with a "tel" scheme when tapping on a phone number.

```
configuration.dataDetectorTypes = .phoneNumber
```

Comment: webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:decisionHandler:] was called more than once'   I get that error

Comment: decisionHandler(.allow) should be in else.

Answer (score 4):

Fixed to make phone call in `WKWebView` by using the "decidePolicyFor navigationAction" delegate method:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    if navigationAction.request.url?.scheme == "tel" {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(navigationAction.request.url!)
        decisionHandler(.cancel)
    } else {
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
}
```

When setting up your web view set the data detector type on its configuration:

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    webView.configuration.dataDetectorTypes = .phoneNumber
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift4**

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {

if navigationAction.targetFrame == nil {

webView.load(navigationAction.request)

}

if navigationAction.request.url?.scheme == "tel" {

UIApplication.shared.openURL(navigationAction.request.url!)

decisionHandler(.cancel)

}

else if navigationAction.request.url?.scheme == "mailto" {

UIApplication.shared.openURL(navigationAction.request.url!)

decisionHandler(.cancel)

}

else{

decisionHandler(.allow)

}

}
```

You can also [see this example](https://subzdesigns.com/blog/WKWebView-tel-mailto-target-blank-check-connection) for your reference. It works on real devices 100%