# WKWebView Tap PhoneNumber And Call Number in xCode 9 - iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift

I have added a WebKit View in my xCode Project and i load my url. Everything works fine but i have 1 problem. If i load a extern .HTML file with a phone number and if i click/tap on that.. Nothing happens.. in the UIWebView it works fine.. I can tap on the number and then i can call it.

How can i make this work for the WKWebView? So that if i click on a number the ios scheme will appear and then i can press call for call the number?
The mail i also not working, If I Tap/click.. Nothing happen s...

I have already tried this: [Catch and call telephone number in WKWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33643326/catch-and-call-telephone-number-in-wkwebview) But it gives me only error messages. So that is not working for me

I'm using **xCode 9** with **Swift 3.2** and building for **iOS 11**

See screenshots and my code

I will appreciate if someone can help me out with this :) Thanks!

[xCode Sreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/in93S.png)

**xCode Code**

```
//
//  InfoController.swift
//  MyApp
//
//  Created by Me - 25/10/2017
//  Copyright © 2017. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import WebKit

class InfoViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var InfoWebView: WKWebView!

    let url = URLAddress()

    @IBAction func backButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string: "https://www.mywebsite.com/info.html")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)

        InfoWebView.load(request)

    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

**HTML CODE**

```
 <a href="mailto:my@mail.com">my@mail.com</a>
 <a href="tel:010-333-2222">010 333 2222</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have a legal `tel` URL. Getting the format right is tricky. See http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2806.txt and other relevant documentation.

After some modification, I found that your URLs work fine for me, so the problem might merely be your expectation as to what should happen:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Thanks for you reply.. I also tried: <a href="tel:+358-555-1234567"> its not working..  and this: tel:+3585551234567 is also not working and mail <a href="mailto:info@myemail.com">is also not working DO you maybe have a other fix? please let me know

Comment: Added screen shot showing what happens for me. You have not explained what "not working" means, so I can't say what the difference might be.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your reply and help. If i tap then nothing happens..no reaction/no dialog showing just nothing... wich modifications did you made? Can i maybe download your xcode project file so that i can compare it whith mine? I would appreciate it! Thanks

Comment: Are you testing on a device? There are no phone calls on the simulator, obviously... Are you just tapping, or are you long-pressing?

Comment: Yes i am testing on a  device (iphone 7) Long Pressing is working but tapping is not working..