# Phone links are clickable in WebKit View, but don't dial

Tags: swift, webview, webkit, tel

I am trying to get telephone links to work in WebKit View.

adding

```
override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webConfiguration.dataDetectorTypes = .phoneNumber
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }
```

has gotten the webView to detect numbers as phone numbers that you can click on, but nothing happens when I click on them.

EDIT: I found out that if you hold a link down, a bunch of options come up that allow you to call it. However, I want to know how to get it to automatically pop up with the alert to confirm the call.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Catch and call telephone number in WKWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33643326/catch-and-call-telephone-number-in-wkwebview)