# How can someone allow unsupported URLs in cordova (IOS)

Tags: cordova, angular6, cordova-plugins, cordova-ios

I'm using a small Cordova app that basically opens my website using InAppBrowser,
On my website, the user able to call us using this line:

```
<a href="tel:xxxxxxxxxxx">
```

I encountered a problem with **IOS devices only** when trying to call, the button is not working or not responding.
I dug in and debugged with **XCODE** and saw that the click to call return an error -

**Failed to load resource: unsupported URL**

Of course, I search on the web and tried multiple solutions like:

1. Alter config.xml and index.html (Cordova)

```
config.xml:
 <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
 <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
 <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
 <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
 <allow-intent href="market:*" />
 <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
 <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
 <allow-navigation href="http://localhost" />
 <allow-navigation href="*" />
 <access origin="*" />
```

```
index.html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * cdvfile: filesystem: file: data: ; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; media-src *">
```

2. Use Safe.pipe (Angular6 on my website) to sanitize the URL

```
this.sanitize.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url)
```

3. Follow the cordova whitelist plugin insturctions

```
$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
$ cordova prepare
<!-- Allow tel: links to open the dialer -->
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
```

I did some other checks but the above are the primary,

I appreciate all the help and the support :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the plugin [cordova-plugin-phone-call](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-phone-call) or do the modification by hand following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33643326/catch-and-call-telephone-number-in-wkwebview)

If you wish to capture and handle more than just tel, and open with default app, you can check out [cordova-plugin-openwith](https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-openwith).

Comment: it doesn't solve the root problem of unsupported URL, because for other URLs that are not tel: I will have this problem again but thanks! I will try it.
For now, I don't want to use modification by hand because it's not maintainable nor recommended to perform.

Comment: Hey,
Thanks for the response!
I had some time to read about this plugin and correct me if I'm wrong but this plugin is helpful in handling files and sharing, not specifically help with click to call or click to open Whatsapp and etc.

Comment: I don't think you understand what's going on here. Just capture a click on any field then call your plugin to open that link with something. It's not going to be automated. You are looking for a too easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

I also have a cordova-ios app that was not pulling up the phone dialer prompt for href=tel anchor tags. FWIW I tried the cordova-plugin-phone-call but that wasn't working for me - nor was any kind of config.xml adjustment. What got things working for me was the info from this link: [“tel”, “sms”, and “mailto” no longer working in Android after upgrading to cordova 3.6.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26271313/tel-sms-and-mailto-no-longer-working-in-android-after-upgrading-to-cordo). Here's my before/after for reference for anyone in the same boat:

Before (not working):

```
<a href="tel:1123456789">Call Number</a>
```

After (working):

```
<a href="Javascript:app.openNativeAppWindow('tel:1123456789');">Call Number</a>
// NOTE: Use the link above to include the instantiation of 
// openNativeAppWindow in your app init object.
```

*My setup for reference: cordova 11.0.0, cordova-ios: 6.2.0 and an iPhone iOS 16.3.1*

Comment: That links a dubious stack overflow scraper site. The original link it's copied from is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26271313/tel-sms-and-mailto-no-longer-working-in-android-after-upgrading-to-cordo